File download has no file extension using Content-Disposition
I'm working with PHP in the Symfony Framework (or at least some components of the Framework). I generate a QR-Code and now I want to download it for our design department. There are 2 problems appearing. 1. My downloaded file has no file extension and 2. The downloaded file is named like a GUID (e. g. aebceb64-c8e1-48d6-b04b-69d4e2959f75).
I want the output to be "cp_qrcode.eps". Here is what I did:
public function downloadQrCode()
    {
        $filePath = __DIR__ . '/../../../../../../var/temp/cp_qrcode.eps';

        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
            exit;
        }

        if (ob_get_level()) {
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/postscript');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cp_qrcode.eps"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));

        return readfile($filePath);
    }

EDIT: Response Headers that reached client side:


What response headers do you see on the client side?

Flushing the output buffer there makes little sense, IMHO. If you already had stuff to in the buffer to flush at this point, then you would not be able to add response headers any more afterwards. If anything, this should be ob_clean to discard the current buffer contents.

@CBroe 1. Added an image with the response headers. 2. Thanks for pointing that out. I removed that.

Cache-Control: no-store could be problematic, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71939201/1427878

Removed no store. Doesn't appear on client side anymore. Still the same issue

Check the readfile() manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php
It looks like it returns the number of bytes read which is not what you want to return. You should try file_get_contents($filePath). An other advice is to correct your file path with "/var/temp/cp_qrcode.eps" so you can move your app and your code will not break.
EDIT: If you want to use readfile, remove the return and die(); or exit(); after the readfile.
